# Populate Element with Text from another Element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I would like to populate an element with the same text as another element using jQuery

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
   <p>text to be populated in another div</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
   <p></p>
</div>
```

So using jQuery, I would like to populate div2's paragraph tag with the text in div1's paragraph tag.

So div2 would look like this after jQuery is preformed

```
<div class="div2">
   <p>text to be populated in another div</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

-Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get the element and update HTML using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```js
$('.div2 p').html($('.div1 p').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p>text to be populated in another div</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text()` function of jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/text/

```js
$(".div2 p").text($(".div1 p").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
   <p>text to be populated in another div</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
   <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Pranav answered just a bit before you and his solution was correct. I gave you an upvote though

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.div2').html($('.div1').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var content = $(".div1 p").html();
$(".div2 p").html(content);});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Pranav answered just a bit before you and his solution was correct. I gave you an upvote though

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the css selector for that p tag in div2

```
$(".div2 p").html($(".div1 p").html())
```

Here is an example

```js
$("#link").click(function(){
  $(".div2 p").html($(".div1 p").html())
})
```

```css
.div1{
background-color:yellow;  
}
.div2{
background-color:green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  This is Div 1
   <p>text to be populated in another div</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    This is Div 2
   <p></p>
</div>

<a id="link" href="#">Click to move data from Div 1 to Div 2</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Pranav answered just a bit before you and his solution was correct. I gave you an upvote though